# OSError:[ WinError 6] The handle is invalid when running powershell commands from python

Tags: python, powershell

When compiling the following code with `pyinstaller` using the following command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --uac-admin --noconsole test.py
```

it throws the following error

```
  File "os.py", line 985, in popen
  File "subprocess.py", line 832, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1267, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

but when compiling the same code without `--noconsole` it works without any errors.

test.py

```
from os import popen

def test_ps():
   result = popen('powershell.exe -encodedcommand ZQBjAGgAbwAgAGgAZQBsAGwAbwA= ').read()
   return result 

print(test_ps())
```

The end goal is to execute powershell commands in a pyinstaller compiled script without a console using the option `--noconsole`

ps the encode command is simply `echo hello`
to decode string

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('ZQBjAGgAbwAgAGgAZQBsAGwAbwA='))
```

Comment: The error message suggests that the PowerShell process attempts to access a console, which by definition doesn't exist, due to `--noconsole`. Instead of `os.popen()`, you _may_ have better luck with [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), which allows you to launch `powershell.exe` without involvement of the default shell (`cmd.exe`) and allows you to custom-bind all standard-stream handles.